# Generic Method always returning NULL

Tags: c#, generics, caching, generic-method

I have a generic method (already developed by another developer way back) in my project for fetching cache; though I have values for the key the method still returns `NULL`.

Please take a look on the code:

```
public static C GetFromCache<C>(string key) where C : class     
    {     
       if (cache != null)
       {
          var testCache = cache.Get(key); // This variable is getting results
          C p = cache.Get(key) as C; this point value of 'p' is NULL
          return p; 
        }

        return null;
    }
```

method call:

```
var lstCheck = ClassName.GetFromCache< List< int >(key);
```

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqFCQ.png)

Comment: Please insert ALL your code in a code block.

Comment: What contains `key`?

Comment: If it not `null`, show us the code of `cache.Get()` please!

Comment: key is just a string like 'cache~04/17/2019'

Comment: Yes, but where hte code here it got its value?

Comment: Also, what `testCache` used for?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Is your `cache` not `null`?

Comment: Your cache isn't returning an object that can be converted to type C, this is why you're getting null. What are you using to cache your objects?

Comment: None of this even compiles... well at least `var lstCheck = ClassName.GetFromCache< List< int >(key);` doesn't

Comment: Yes I debugged the code it's not null

Comment: Try `C p = (C)cache.Get(key)` instead of `C p = cache.Get(key) as C`. Tell us about exceptions thrown.

Comment: ohh issue resolved.. 
I already tried the solution which @ChayimFriedman posted. However I didn't allow the process to be completed.
It's a type cast exception.
Thanks a lot Chayim Friedman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the result of `cache.Get(key)` isn't a *C type*. Let me explain with code:

```
Object name = "my-name";
var nameAsString = name as String; // name is already a String, so nameAsString = "my-name"
var nameAsRandom = name as Random; // name isn't Random, so nameAsRandom == null
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks a lot It solved my issue..